# How to perform LU-decomposition with OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, eigen

The cvInvert() method takes a flag CV_LU that does the LU factorisation to invert an input matrix. However is there any way to obtain the L and U matrices that are formed during this computation?
  Is seems pointless to write a new function for LU-decomposition is OpenCV already has optimized code for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like OpenCV gives you a way to access the L and U matrices. [Here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/lapack.cpp) is how the function is implemented. And, it looks like for performance reasons LU-decomposition is done in-place. So, you will probably have to do it on your own.

**EDIT:** It appears that after looking at both how Matlab and Eigen do LU-decomposition you can actually retrieve them after the cvInvert call. The L matrix is the **strictly** lower-triangle matrix of the result plus the Identity matrix, and the U matrix is the upper triangle matrix.

**EDIT:** [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) actually integrates fairly well with OpenCV. And, it appears they have an LU decomposition class implemented [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1FullPivLU.html). Eigen is already a dependency for OpenCV if you built it yourself, you should have it available to use (it's completely implemented in header files, so that makes it really easy to use). There is also an OpenCV header implementing the conversion between Eigen matrices and OpenCV matrices @ `#include <opencv2/core/eigen.hpp>`.

However, at least on my SVN build, this header didn't work right, so I made my own:

```
#ifndef __OPENCV_CORE_EIGEN_HPP__
#define __OPENCV_CORE_EIGEN_HPP__

#ifdef __cplusplus

#include "opencv/cxcore.h"
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

namespace cv
{

template<typename _Tp, int _rows, int _cols, int _options, int _maxRows, int _maxCols>
void eigen2cv( const Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, _rows, _cols, _options, _maxRows, _maxCols>& src, Mat& dst )
{
    if( !(src.Flags & Eigen::RowMajorBit) )
    {
        Mat _src(src.cols(), src.rows(), DataType<_Tp>::type,
              (void*)src.data(), src.stride()*sizeof(_Tp));
        transpose(_src, dst);
    }
    else
    {
        Mat _src(src.rows(), src.cols(), DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 (void*)src.data(), src.stride()*sizeof(_Tp));
        _src.copyTo(dst);
    }
}

template<typename _Tp, int _rows, int _cols, int _options, int _maxRows, int _maxCols>
void cv2eigen( const Mat& src,
               Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, _rows, _cols, _options, _maxRows, _maxCols>& dst )
{
    CV_DbgAssert(src.rows == _rows && src.cols == _cols);
    if( !(dst.Flags & Eigen::RowMajorBit) )
    {
        Mat _dst(src.cols, src.rows, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        if( src.type() == _dst.type() )
            transpose(src, _dst);
        else if( src.cols == src.rows )
        {
            src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
            transpose(_dst, _dst);
        }
        else
            Mat(src.t()).convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
    else
    {
        Mat _dst(src.rows, src.cols, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
}

template<typename _Tp>
void cv2eigen( const Mat& src,
               Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>& dst )
{
    dst.resize(src.rows, src.cols);
    if( !(dst.Flags & Eigen::RowMajorBit) )
    {
        Mat _dst(src.cols, src.rows, DataType<_Tp>::type,
             dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        if( src.type() == _dst.type() )
            transpose(src, _dst);
        else if( src.cols == src.rows )
        {
            src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
            transpose(_dst, _dst);
        }
        else
            Mat(src.t()).convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
    else
    {
        Mat _dst(src.rows, src.cols, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
}


template<typename _Tp>
void cv2eigen( const Mat& src,
               Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>& dst )
{
    CV_Assert(src.cols == 1);
    dst.resize(src.rows);

    if( !(dst.Flags & Eigen::RowMajorBit) )
    {
        Mat _dst(src.cols, src.rows, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        if( src.type() == _dst.type() )
            transpose(src, _dst);
        else
            Mat(src.t()).convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
    else
    {
        Mat _dst(src.rows, src.cols, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
}


template<typename _Tp>
void cv2eigen( const Mat& src,
               Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, 1, Eigen::Dynamic>& dst )
{
    CV_Assert(src.rows == 1);
    dst.resize(src.cols);
    if( !(dst.Flags & Eigen::RowMajorBit) )
    {
        Mat _dst(src.cols, src.rows, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        if( src.type() == _dst.type() )
            transpose(src, _dst);
        else
            Mat(src.t()).convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
    else
    {
        Mat _dst(src.rows, src.cols, DataType<_Tp>::type,
                 dst.data(), (size_t)(dst.stride()*sizeof(_Tp)));
        src.convertTo(_dst, _dst.type());
        CV_DbgAssert(_dst.data == (uchar*)dst.data());
    }
}

}

#endif

#endif
```

Hopefully that is helpful to you!

Comment: thanks. i was thinking of using Boost or something, this Eigen seems less of a hassle.

Comment: Your explanation on LU decomposition in MATLAB and Eigen is a little bit misleading, because L itself is not a strictly lower triangular matrix. It is the strictly lower part of A plus the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Corrected and updated the links as most were dead.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the function `Cholesky()` provided by OpenCV (using 2.4.6), see source code of `modules\stitching\src\autocalib.cpp`. But it needs some scaling to get a comparable result with Matlab:

```
Mat chol = mat.clone();
if (Cholesky(chol.ptr<float>(), chol.step, chol.cols, 0, 0, 0))
{
    Mat diagElem = chol.diag();
    for (int e = 0; e < diagElem.rows; ++e)
    {
        float elem = diagElem.at<float>(e);
        chol.row(e) *= elem;
        chol.at<float>(e,e) = 1.0f / elem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the meaning of the arguments to OpenCV's Cholesky?  Also, what is the actual output of the OpenCV Cholesky function in relation to the Cholesky decomposition A=LL* (where * denotes conjugate transpose)?