# Cholesky Decomposition of matrix in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, matrix, decomposition, matrix-decomposition

is there any function in OpenCV that I can use to apply Cholesky Decomposition on a matrix?

Comment: Although both `solve` and `invert` give you the option of using cholesky decomposition internally, the actual function itself does not seem to be exposed. There are a few bits of OpenCV like that. It shouldn't take you too long to cobble together your own code to do the same job, however.

Comment: If you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861772/how-to-perform-lu-decomposition-with-opencv, someone actually gives an answer showing how to use `Cholesky()` (instead of the LU which was asked about). `Cholesky()` doesn't seemed to be documented, but it is in operations.hpp.

Answer (score 2):

If still relevant, OCV 3.0.0 supports Cholesky directly through the HAL interface. See [cv::hal::Cholesky](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/d6/d19/namespacecv_1_1hal.html#a5e6f641b2178e58571627342403319b7)

Comment: There's also a proxy in `cv` namespace. See the doc [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gab39ce257149bdae7f9552e05c05c7642&gsc.tab=0)

Comment: Do you know the meaning of the arguments to OpenCV's Cholesky? Also, what is the actual output of the OpenCV Cholesky function in relation to the Cholesky decomposition A=LL* (where * denotes conjugate transpose)?