# Cholesky factorization in cublas

Tags: cuda, gpu, cublas, matrix-factorization

I am new to cuda programming. I want to perform Cholesky factorization for small matrics(8*8) .Is there any algorithm to get it by using CUBLAS batch functions

cuda version-6.5

Thank you

Comment: Have you already searched through the cuBLAS User Guide?

Comment: yes, I couldn’t find anything ..

Comment: Then you already know the answer.

Comment: An alternative is to use the Cholesky decomposition function in OpenCV. Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861772/how-to-perform-lu-decomposition-with-opencv) to the code.

Comment: @Eagle I have found out that the eigen (both with and without mkl ) is worse in precision than the new cuda solver, if set to float. On double, they are both just as precise.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix sizes are too small to see any benefit from GPU.
However, the new cuda 7 version provides cuSolver module ( http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html ) that can do what you ask. I suggest looking it up. Also, consider sticking to CPU and Eigen library.

Answer (score 1):

Cholesky factorization in CUDA: http://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~stg20/cuda/cholesky/